# RoR - undefined method `hello' for Karlsgem::KarlsGeming:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

undefined method `hello' for Karlsgem::KarlsGeming:Class

please help, I just want it to display the string in the View an cant seem to wrap my head around this?? am I in the wrong file?

karlsgem.rb

```
require "karlsgem/version"

module Karlsgem
    class KarlsGeming
        def hello
            puts "Hello World"
        end

    end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<% if notice %>
<p id="notice" ><%= notice %></p>
<% end %>

<%= @kgem %>

<h1>Your Drinks Catalog</h1>
<% @products.each do |product| %>
<div class="entry" >
<%= image_tag(product.image_url) %>
<h3><%= product.title %></h3>
<%=sanitize product.description %>
<div class="price_line" >
<span class="price" >€<%= product.price %></span>
<%= button_to 'Add to Cart' , line_items_path(:product_id => product) %>
</div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

store_controller.rb

```
require 'karlsgem'

class StoreController < ApplicationController
  def index
@products = Product.all
@cart = current_cart

@kgem = Karlsgem::KarlsGeming.hello

  end
end
```

Comment: its just calling the method from the gem, not to sure why im getting the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined hello as an instance method. In order to do `Karlsgem::KarlsGeming.hello` you would have to define it as a class method:

```
require "karlsgem/version"
module Karlsgem
  class KarlsGeming
    def self.hello
        puts "Hello World"
    end
  end
end
```